# Ajax PageMethods is not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following javascript calling webmethd in asp.net

```
 function passpd(elem) {
        if (confirm("You sure you want to delete") == true) {
            var exID = $(elem).closest('table').attr('id');
            exID = exID.replace("_fawad", '');
            alert(exID + "abc");
            PageMethods.DeleteInfo1("fawad", exID, "OnSuccessD", "OnErrorD");
            alert("2");
            var d1= $(elem).closest('table').attr('id');
            $("#" + d1).remove();
            return false;

        }
        else { alert("cancel deletion");return false;}
    }
```

And my webmethod is as follow,

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string DeleteInfo1(string pname, string id) 
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ProfileOne.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string sql = "delete from Experience where ProfileName=@p and ExperienceID=@e";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@e", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        con.Open();
        int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (ret > 0) { return "ok"; }
        else { return "nok"; }

    }
```

The problem is the webmthod is not getting called. the first alert in passpd() function is getting called but the PageMthods.DeleteInfo1 is not getting executed.

What is the problem. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a post to the method. I'm not sure if what you do after the post is dependent on the result of the action but if, you would have to put it inside the `$.post` where `//do something here` is.

```
   function passpd(elem) {
            if (confirm("You sure you want to delete") == true) {
                var exID = $(elem).closest('table').attr('id');
                exID = exID.replace("_fawad", '');
                alert(exID + "abc"); 


                $.post('/PageMethods/DeleteInfo1/', { pname: 'fawad', id: exID }, function() {
                    //do something here?
                });


                alert("2");
                var d1= $(elem).closest('table').attr('id');
                $("#" + d1).remove();

                return false;
            }
            else { alert("cancel deletion");return false;}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

I was using url rewriting so. Just came to me when I was going through my code